# Can MyBatis be used with SAP Hybris database?

Tags: mybatis, dao, sap-commerce-cloud, data-access-layer, bapi

Is it possible to use MyBatis on top of an SAP Hybris database?

Or does this require some customization to use SAP BAPIs/Interfaces, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Hybris using jdbc and it has hard coded functionality by some jdbc driver. It is not supported all jdbc driver. I think using MyBatis is impossible for hybris ootb db.

Maybe you can use it in some custom classes.